# Do Console.Log Laravel If Authentication Is Successfull

Tags: laravel

I need to make a `console.log(user_id + ' signed-in successfully');` on user's successful login.

My problem is where and how would I place the trigger?

This is the only thing that I can see on my `Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController:`

```php
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/master.php';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showLogin()
    {
        return view('page.login_form');
    }
```

Any advised?

**UPDATE:**

My actual purpose is that I want to notify the other signed-in users that a new user has just signed-in using socket.io. This part is I know how to do.

I also know how to do toastr notification from a controller. say when a user saved a certain record. Which is triggering a javascript from a controller - same thing what I want to accomplish during the user login.

That's why if I can only do the `console.log()` on the login, I can do it from there.

Comment: JavaScript and PHP execute at different times. The more pressing question would be why would you want that logged? Surely it's self-evident when the user has successfully signed in?

Comment: @Script47 - please check my update, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using the `authenticated` method inside the `LoginController`.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
  // Session::flash(); --> PUT MY CODE HERE TO FIRE THE console.log();

  return redirect()->route('');
}
```

Comment: This surely is a better option.. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `/landing` page whose sole purpose will be to notify other user and then redirect again to `/master.php`.

You need to change to `protected $redirectTo = '/landing';`. You should also insert a middleware to make sure without logging in a user won't be able to go to `/landing`.

At `/landing` page you will fire the notification and then redirect to `/master.php`. From there you will continue normal operations.

Comment: i think this would work, if no one else make an answer I will try this tomorrow. thank you for your time.

Comment: so weird, i changed the `$redirectTo` value, setup the route and method for it but it is not working. i put a `dd('stop');` inside the method but it is not firing.

Comment: Try this. Go to 'app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthinticated.php'. Check that file. I reckon in your case it has something like return redirect('/home'); which should be changed to appropriate route.

Comment: yup, i've been there and I tried to `dd()` the value and it really outputs the value of `$redirectTo` that's why it is weird that the method for that route was not firing.

Comment: anyway, i had solved the problem. i have discovered that you can use the `authenticated` method inside the `LoginController`.